# cannot find function in this scope not found in this scope in Rust

Tags: rust

Guys, I am new to rust, and I am tring to do recursion inside a Train Implement, Here is My code:

```
impl Solution {
   pub fn some_fun() {
     ...
     some_fun(); // Err: cannot find function `some_fun` in this scope not found in this scoperustcE0425
     ...
   }
}
```

how can I fix this code ?

Comment: You can use `Self::some_fun();` too

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are defining an associated function to the struct `Solution`. Therefore it is scoped under `Solution`.

Unlike languages like Java, Rust does not magically resolve things that are part of the current class. You need to specify the path to the thing you are attempting to use. In this case, it would be something like:

```rust
impl Solution {
   pub fn some_fun() {
     // ...
     Solution::some_fun();
     // ...
   }
}
```